# Box2d: How to get cursor position to apply a velocity to a dynamic body in that direction?

Tags: c++, qt, box2d

I want to apply a velocity vector to a dynamic body in the cursor direction:

```
void Game::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e){

    double angle = atan2(realBall->GetPosition().y - e->pos().y(), realBall->GetPosition().x - e->pos().x());
    realBall->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(-cos(angle) * 50, -sin(angle) * 50));
 }
```

But the dynamic body has an incorrect direction, so i think that the cursor position it's wrong.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i get the cursor coordinate to apply a velocity to this body

Comment: Please read about [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must know that in order for your code to work, the coordinates of your screen and the coordinates of box2d must match. Be aware that if you use screen coordinates in pixels, it means that the size of one pixel matches an 1 meter in box2d. But let’s assume that you have already taken all this into account. Then I would not advise you to use trigonometry for calculations. So you can easily make a mistake. In this case, simple vector operations will be enough for you: substraction, scaling and normalizing a vector. You can try this: velocity = (cursor_position - real_ball_position).normalize().scale(50f). In box2d there is a b2Vec class for vector operations. You can read about it in detail in the documentation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).